# I'm not able to get text value from a disabled text

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to get value from a disabled text box

This is what I'm tried

```java
WebElement text= driver.findElement(By.id("text"));
System.out.println("text= " +ssn.getAttribute("value"));
```

```html
<input _ngcontent-c10="" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine" id="text" name="TEXT" placeholder="12345" type="text" disabled="">
```

It is printing this

```
text = null
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `input` element has no `value` attribute, so `.getAttribute("value"));` is useless

Your element have the following attribute :

- _ngcontent-c10
- class
- id
- name
- placeholder
- type
- disabled

May this is what you mean :

```
WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='text']"));
System.out.println("text= " +text.getAttribute("placeholder"));
```

It will get `12345`